# Optimizing code to run through 2 or more sets of data efficiently

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization, interface

Hi I was given this problem in which it takes too long for this program to run and I was tasked to make it go faster

```js
interface Payroll {
  empNo: string;
  vacationDays: number;
}

interface AddressBook {
  empNo: string;
  email: string;
}

interface WorkHistory {
  empNo: string;
  name: string;
  yearsEmployed: number;
}

interface EmailApi {
  sendEmail(email: string, body: string);
}

// We haved decided to grant bonus vacation to every employee, 1 day per year of experience
// we need to email them a notice
EmailVacationGrant(
  emailApi: EmailApi,
  workHistory: WorkHistory[],
  addressBook: AddressBook[],
  payroll: Payroll[],
) {
  for(int i=0; i<workHistory.length; ++i) {
    let employee = wh[i];
    let address = addressBook.find(x => x.empNo==employee.empNo);
    let payroll = payroll.find(x => x.empNo==employee.empNo);

    let newVacationBalance = employee.yearsEmployed + payroll.vacationDays;
    emailApi.sendEmail(
      address.email,
      `Dear ${employee.name}\n` +
      `based on your ${employee.yearsEmployed} years of employment, you have been granted ${employee.yearsEmployed} days of vacation, bringing your total to ${newVacationBalance}`);
  }
}
```

After doing some research I learned most if not all browsers do not like the `.find` method and prefer a general `for` loop. Knowing this I thought it would have been appropriate to just put everything in one interface. My solution is as follows

```js
interface WorkHistory {
  empNo: string;
  vacationDays: number;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  yearsEmployed: number;
}

interface EmailApi {
  sendEmail(email: string, body: string);
}

// We haved decided to grant bonus vacation to every employee, 1 day per year of experience
// we need to email them a notice
EmailVacationGrant(
  emailApi: EmailApi,
  workHistory: WorkHistory[],
) {
  for(int i=0; i<workHistory.length; ++i) { // in js a for loop is much faster the .find however I wanted to stick with to make sure the time complexity wasnt too huge
    let employee = wh[i];
    let address = employee.email;
    let payroll = employee.payroll;

    let newVacationBalance = employee.yearsEmployed + employee.vacationDays;
    emailApi.sendEmail(
      employee.email,
      `Dear ${employee.name}\n` +
      `based on your ${employee.yearsEmployed} years of employment, you have been granted ${employee.yearsEmployed} days of vacation, bringing your total to ${newVacationBalance}`);
  }
}
```

Is there any other faster way especially one that doesn't require me messing up with the interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of `Array.find` should be `O(n)` which in your case is fairly good and won't get any better. As you already tried to, in your case the best solution would be to extend the interface. If you're not able to change those, may just extend them.
We do not know much about your data model and how you fetch those details on the employee but on the UX side the best solution is always that you get the required data with a single request. If this is not possible may go for early loading and mapping this data before you run into your method.

The code you supplied is good, you may want to change all occurrences of `let` with `const`.